# Inno Setup - How to edit a specific line from a text file during setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to edit a specific line from a text file using Inno Setup. I need my installer to find this line (`"appinstalldir"     "C:MYXFOLDER\\apps\\common\\App70"`) and use the directory path from the installer.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    SaveStringToFile(
      ExpandConstant('{app}\app70.txt'),
      'directory's path' + '\\apps\\common\\App70', True);
  end;
end;
```

This is my text file:

```
"App"
{
    "appID"     "70"

    {
        "appinstalldir"     "C:MYXFOLDER\\apps\\common\\App70"
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that whatever writes that file is very strict. If it happens to put `{` or `}` ont he same line then the parsign will break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code can do it. But note, that this code doesn't check, if the value for the tag is enclosed by quote chars, once it finds a tag specified by `TagName` parameter, it cuts off the rest of the line and appends the value given by `TagValue` parameter:

```pascal
function ReplaceValue(const FileName, TagName, TagValue: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  Tag: string;
  Line: string;
  TagPos: Integer;
  FileLines: TStringList;
begin
  Result := False;
  FileLines := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Tag := '"' + TagName + '"';
    FileLines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    for I := 0 to FileLines.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Line := FileLines[I];
      TagPos := Pos(Tag, Line);
      if TagPos > 0 then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Delete(Line, TagPos + Length(Tag), MaxInt);
        Line := Line + ' "' + TagValue + '"';
        FileLines[I] := Line;
        FileLines.SaveToFile(FileName);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FileLines.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  NewPath: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    NewPath := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\apps\common\App70';
    StringChangeEx(NewPath, '\', '\\', True);

    if ReplaceValue(ExpandConstant('{app}\app70.txt'), 'appinstalldir', 
      NewPath) 
    then
      MsgBox('Tag value has been replaced!', mbInformation, MB_OK)
    else  
      MsgBox('Tag value has not been replaced!.', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Mr. TLama, i edited the code like this:
`ReplaceValue(ExpandConstant('{app}\app70.txt'), 'appinstalldir', ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\\apps\\common\\App70')`
I got a good result in the txt file:
"App"
{
    "appID"     "70"

    {
        "appinstalldir"     "C:\Program Files (x86)\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\\apps\\common\\App70"
        }
}`
But i got this problem... My software only read the `"appinstalldir"` directory's path if have this format:
`"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\apps\\common\\App70"` i need to add the extra "\", how can i do that ?

Comment: I see. You need to double the backslashes for the `ExpandConstant('{app}')` part of the new value. Since there is no direct function for doing this, you can use the `StringChangeEx` function, which replaces all occurences of a certain string (or in this case char) to something else. In your case, you can build your path with single backslash and then in this string replace backslashes with double backslashes, like shown in the edited code.